# Returning two lists to VF page from same functions

Tags: visualforce, list

on my VF page I have two grids. One for External attendee and another for staff  members. I have a single Add Attendee button that creates a contact and then adds it to the campaign by creating a campaign member record. On the campaign member record there is a formula field of Type that reads the email address and based on it marks a campaign member record as internal on external. Now, I am writing the logic of creating two lists one of internal and another of external. The issue am facing is how to return two lists and a VF error of Incompatible element type CampaignMemberInfo. Below is the method I have created in the controller class  that is called via remote action:

```
public static list<CampaignMemberInfo> addToCampaignMember(string strCampaignMember,string CampaignToken, string UserToken){

        list<CampaignMemberInfo> lstCampaignMember = new list<CampaignMemberInfo>(); 
        Campaign sCampaign = new Campaign();
        Contact sContact = new Contact();

        try
        {
            sCampaign = Utils.getCampaignDetail(CampaignToken);
            sContact = Utils.getContactDetail(UserToken);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        list<CampaignMember> CampaignMembers = new list<CampaignMember>();
        //09/02/2016 -- Introducing new List to hold internal campaign members
        list<CampaignMember> InternalCampaignMembers = new list<CampaignMember>();

        string[] arrId = strCampaignMember.split(',');

        system.debug('arrId:'+arrId);

        for(id sid : arrId){
            CampaignMember sCM = new CampaignMember();
            sCM.Campaignid  = sCampaign.id;
            sCM.ContactId   = sid;
            sCM.MD_Cal__c   = sContact.id;
            CampaignMembers.add(sCM);
        }
        system.debug('CampaignMembers:'+CampaignMembers);
        // Create Campaign Member
        insert CampaignMembers;

        // 09/02/2016 -- Introducing logic to differentiate between internal and external attendees
        for(CampaignMember sCM : CampaignMembers)
        {   if (SCM.AttendeeType__c == 'External/ Clients')
            lstCampaignMember.add(new CampaignMemberInfo(sCM));
            if (SCM.AttendeeType__c <> 'External/ Clients')
            InternalCampaignMembers.add(new CampaignMemberInfo(sCM));
        }

        return lstCampaignMember;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First up, you should be running into an error trying to save the Apex you've provided. Your method's signature says that you'll return a `List<CampaignMemberInfo>`, but you're returning a `List<CapaignMember>` instead.

Also, just a nit-picky thing, the for loop at the end of your method is probably better off using if-else, rather than 2 if statements. There isn't any danger of having a `CampaignMember` show up in both the internal and external lists, but switching to if-else is more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) which is a Good Thing™

```
// 09/02/2016 -- Introducing logic to differentiate between internal and external attendees
    for(CampaignMember sCM : CampaignMembers)
    {   if (SCM.AttendeeType__c == 'External/ Clients'){
            lstCampaignMember.add(new CampaignMemberInfo(sCM));
        }else{
            InternalCampaignMembers.add(new CampaignMemberInfo(sCM));
        }
    }
```

Those aside, there are two ways I can see to go about this. I'm not sure which one is better if you're using javascript remoting.

**First way**

Instead of returning a `List<CampaignMember>`, return a `List<List<CampaignMember>>` or a `Map<String, List<CampaignMember>>`

If you choose to use the map, the last line of your method could be

```
return new Map<String, List<CampaignMember>>{
    'Internal' => InternalCampaignMembers,
    'External' => lstCampaignMember
};
```

The Visualforce to make use of this could be

```
<apex:repeat value="{!addToCampaignMember}" var="key">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!addToCampaignMember[key]}" var="listItem">
            <apex:column value="{!listItem}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:repeat>
```

Now, this won't work as-is (because `addToCampaignMember` takes arguments), but it illustrates how you can work over a map in Visualforce.

**Second Way**

Don't return anything at all, and change your method signature to

```
public static void addToCampaignMember(string strCampaignMember,string CampaignToken, string UserToken)
```

Instead of returning a value, you'd make your internal and external `List<CampaignMembers>` class attributes/variables, and set those variables in your existing method.

The variable declaration could be

```
public List<CampaignMember> internalMembers {get; private set;}`
```

which would allow you to access the data anywhere in a Visualforce page using something like

```
<apex:repeat var="internal" value="{!internalMembers}">...</apex:repeat>
```

Also, you'd need to initialize the internal/external lists in your controller's constructor, lest you get a `NullPointerException` when attempting to add a value to one of the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Write an Wrapper class where you will have 2 variables of type `List<CampaignMemberInfo>` and `List<CampaignMember>` and then return an instance of the Wrapper class. You can have extra error message variables as well as per your requirements in the Wrapper class. Follow this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class) from Apex guide.

Comment: Thanks Santanu for your reply. Could you please share a sample or link of how this wrapper class needs to be written. Thanks

Comment: updated my answer with link